# Animating JSON data?

Tags: json, api, animation, mustache

Dumb question time. I was trying to integrate my JSON data with a flipbook plugin, using a Mustache templating system. Needless to say, this wasn't working at all.

I'm a jQuery noobie, so is there any easy way to bind and animate the JSON data to/with a plugin (with or without the Mustache tags)??

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "animating" data?

Comment: @Philipp Probably something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/REguz/1/

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I'm looking at using Turn.js for making a page flip animation with jQuery, but it seems to not be working with the mustache templating.

Comment: I think this might be in the realm of what I'm looking for? https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/wiki/Making-pages-dynamically-with-Ajax

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is a bit hard to deduce what you want, but I feel you got already all the pieces together. First the example you have been linking to in a comment:  https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/wiki/Making-pages-dynamically-with-Ajax

This fetches not yet loaded pages via Ajax, and the sample code assumes the Ajax call gets HTML back from the server, as can be seen in the code snippet from there (after adding a missing '}':

```
$.ajax({url: "app?method=get-page-content&page="+page})
  .done(function(data) {
     element.html(data);
});
```

Here the `done` function processes the `data` it got back from the server by straight injecting it into the `element`, which is expected to contain the current page.

I assume next that you do have a server side method, but that method returns JSON instead. Let me assume for the moment that it returns the following structure:

```
{ "title" : "the title of page N", 
  "text"  : "here is some text for the page N." }
```

The next thing is to render this JSON into into html in the `done` funktion, before inserting the result into the page. Looking at the short tutorial on the [README.md](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) this might look like:

```
$.ajax({url: "app?method=get-page-content&page="+page})
  .done(function(data) {
     var pageHtml = Mustache.render("<h2>{{title}}</h2><p>{{text}}</p>", data);
     element.html(pageHtml);
});
```

If the server returns the proper `data` you should now see a

```
<h2>the title of page N</h2><p>here is some text for the page N.</p>
```

appear on the page.